# issues while running webdriver tests using jenkins

Tags: macos, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

OS: MAC
Selenium-Webdriver tests run fine on Firefox driver when run through eclipse but when I try to run using jenkins, all the tests are getting skipped. Can somebody help?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some further information here? Such as your logs? Maybe the Jenkins configuration information?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the surefire or failsafe plugin?

If so, then by default it only picks up classes which match *Test.class.   Do your match that?